# Use introjs in Xaringan Rmarkdown Presentation

Tags: html, css, r, xaringan

I am trying to include an [`introJS`](https://introjs.com/) tour into a xaringan presentation but encounter a formatting error (see screenshots below). I suspect it has something to do with css, but I don't where to start.

Additionally, using the arrows (usually to navigate the tour, when the tour is active), also triggers changing the slides using remark.js. Something I can live with, but would be nice to have it properly working...

Interestingly, the preview window of RStudio renders the user tour correctly.

Any ideas how to fix this?

**A note on rintrojs**: as I am not using `shiny` as a backend, I cannot use the [`rintrojs`](https://github.com/carlganz/rintrojs) package but include the [`intro.js`](https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/blob/master/intro.js) and [`introjs.css`](https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/blob/master/introjs.css) scripts directly.

### Base Rmarkdown example

```r
---
title: "Tester"
output: html_document
---

<!--- Include IntroJS --->
<script language="JavaScript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intro.js/2.9.3/intro.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  @import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intro.js/2.9.3/introjs.min.css");
</style>

<!--- Create divs and button for starting the tour ---> 
<div id="target" data-step="1" data-intro="This is a tooltip!">
TARGET 1
</div>

<div id="target2" data-step="2" data-intro="This is another tooltip!">
TARGET 2
</div>

<a class="btn btn-large btn-success" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:introJs().start();">START INTROJS</a>
```

[image]

### Xaringan Rmarkdown example (broken)

Note that only the yaml-header has changed!

```r
---
title: "Xaringan Tester"
output: xaringan::moon_reader
---

<!--- Include IntroJS --->
<script language="JavaScript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intro.js/2.9.3/intro.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  @import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intro.js/2.9.3/introjs.min.css");
</style>

<!--- Create divs and button for starting the tour ---> 
<div id="target" data-step="1" data-intro="This is a tooltip!">
TARGET 1
</div>

<div id="target2" data-step="2" data-intro="This is another tooltip!">
TARGET 2
</div>

<a class="btn btn-large btn-success" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:introJs().start();">START INTROJS</a>
```

[image]